# Evaluation of $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} dx$$

---

**Update:** I know that this can be solved with many methods and I do know some of them. I'm just searching for the (agreeably) most efficient way to do this.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} = \frac{x}{x^2(x^2+1)}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fastest one is to map $x$ into $\frac{1}{y}$ in order to have:
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x(x^2+1)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{y^2+1}\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\left.\log(1+y^2)\right|_{0}^{1}=\log\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. You're right: this seems the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

First do partial fraction decomposition of the integrand, which will give you:

$$\frac{1}{x} -\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

Then integrate term by term.

The first is easy.

The second can be integrated by substituting $u = x^2+1$ if you can't simply "see" the $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ form immediately.

Lastly, impose the bounds and take the limit for the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(x^2+1)} dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{2x}{2x^2(x^2+1)} dx$$

Set $x^2=u$

$$I=\frac12\int_1^\infty \frac1{u(u+1)} du$$

$$2I=\int_1^\infty \frac{u+1-u}{u(u+1)} du=\int_1^\infty\frac{du}u-\int_1^\infty\frac{du}{u+1}=\ln\frac u{u+1}|_1^\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+x^2-x^2}{x(x^2+1)}dx=$$

$$\ =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\pars{x^{2} + 1}}}
=-\Im\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\pars{x + \ic}}
=-\Im\int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over x + \ic} - {1 \over x}}\,{\dd x \over -\ic}
\\[5mm]&=-\Re\int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over x + \ic} - {1 \over x}}\,\dd x
=\left. -\Re\ln\pars{x + \ic \over x}\right\vert_{1}^{\infty}=\Re\ln\pars{1 + \ic}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\half\,\ln\pars{2}}\approx{\tt 0.3466}
\end{align}